# Capturing java and native memory dumps

Tags: android, memory-leaks, adb

I need to know whether both java and native memory dump can be obtained by executing the commands for both simultaneously for android. 
For java, we execute `adb shell am dumpheap <pid> /path/to/dump/file`
For native, we execute `adb shell am dumpheap -n <pid> /path/to/dump/file`.

Can we execute both the commands simultaneously and does anyone have an impact on the other? Like after obtaining the java memory dump does the native memory dump get affected?